# Transform table by moving values from two last columns to newly created merged cells in row below

Tags: transformation

I want to create a report. It will contain selected rows and columns from larger table. Since two columns contains long strings I would like to move them below and make them more visible by merging cells. This it the table I would like to transform:
[source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUp12.png)
and I would like it to look like this:
[taget table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OjzB.png)

Currently I'm using officer and flextable R packages to create report, but maybe there are better options? I'm open to suggestions and other languages beside R.